# unexpected spacing at the end of line by placing two images over eachother CSS

Tags: html, css, image

I'm trying to place a picture over another picture with css. That works fine. But I'm having a problem that there is unexpected spacing at the end of the first line of my paragraph. i don't know how I can fix this.
I hope somebody can help me.
http://jsfiddle.net/76j8W/1/

my html looks like this:

```
<img id="firstpic" src="http://images7.alphacoders.com/407/407975.jpg" />
<img id="duck" src="http://clipartist.info/openclipart.org/2011/Sept/Sep2011_Art/rubber_duck-1331px.png " />
<p> sometext </p>
```

My css looks like this:

```
#firstpic{
width:100%;
padding:0;
margin:auto;
}


#duck{
 width:45px;
 position: relative;
 z-index:999;
 top:-50px;
 float:right;
}

p{
text-align:justify; 
}
```

Comment: It's due to the relative re-positioning of the duck image. When you move the image, the space it originally occupied remains.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

instead of

```
top: -50px
```

use

```
margin-top: -50px;
```

Example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yMv9L/

`margin-top` set a distance of the element from others, so this property will also affect the  surrounding elements (the paragraph, in the given example). When you change instead the position of an element in `relative` position and you move it with `top`, it is "translated" from its original place but the space left from the element is still seen from other elements (as if it was in static position)

---

resulting effect

[image]

Comment: you should add some explanation for the cause of the problem (which relates to how `relative` positioning works).